# Prolog task with pigs, exception error

Tags: prolog, logic

I've got this pig riddle...what do I do wrong here? it fails with the uncaught exception (below!). I need to output what does each pig eat and where it comes from as the result. Could someone rectify what I've done wrong. Thanks in advance.

```
all_pigs([H],L2) :- pig(H,L2).
all_pigs([H|T],L2) :- pig(H,L2), all_pigs(T, L2).

or([H]) :- H,!.
or([H|_]) :- H,!.
or([_|T]) :- or(T).

solve(Kunekune, Landrasse, Schwarzfussschwein, Haegenauchschwein) :-

    Kunekune = [Kunekune_land, Kunekune_food],
    Landrasse = [Landrasse_land, Landrasse_food],
    Schwarzfussschwein = [Schwarzfussschwein_land, Schwarzfussschwein_food],
    Haegenauchschwein = [Haegenauchschwein_land, Haegenauchschwein_food],

All = [Kunekune, Landrasse, Schwarzfussschwein, Haegenauchschwein],
all_pigs([japan, danemark,france, australia], [Kunekune_land, Landrasse_land, Schwarzfussschwein_land, Haegenauchschwein_land]),
all_pigs([grass, vegetables, eggs, chestnuts], [Kunekune_food, Landrasse_food, Schwarzfussschwein_food, Haegenauchschwein_food]),

Landrasse = [danemark,Landrasse_food],
pig([japan, vegeables], All),
pig([australia, !(eggs)], All),
Schwarzfussschwein = [Schwarzfussschwein_land, chestnuts],
Kunekune = [!(france), grass].
```

uncaught exception: error(existence_error(procedure,pig/2),all_pigs/2)

Comment: You don't have a predicate or fact defined anywhere `pig/2` (which is `pig` with two arguments). You do use a term `pig/2` in your code, but not as a fact or predicate head.

Comment: doesn't matter, I've solved it!

Comment: Yay! Glad to hear it. You could, if you wish, post an answer to your own question if you think others would benefit.

Comment: By the way, if you have `or([H|_]) :- H,!.` then you don't need `or([H]) :- H,!.` since `[H]` is equivalent to `[H|[]]`.